# insert values from array

Tags: php, arrays, insert

im using phpexcel to read my xls, i dont have problems with that, but when im trying to insert values in my database appear this on console "Array to string conversion".

code:

```
 $inputFileName = $_FILES['xls']['tmp_name'];
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
    // ------------------ COMISIONES ------------------ //
    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(2);
    $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
    $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
        $rowData[] = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);            
        foreach ($rowData[0] as $var) {
          $sql = "INSERT INTO bd_comisiones (registro,clave,nombre,rfc,comision,iva,subtotal,retencion,neto,prestamos,neto_a_recibir) VALUES ('" . implode(",", $var) . "')";
          $sql_insert = $conexion->prepare($sql);
          $sql_insert->execute();
        }
    }
```

array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Registro
                    [1] => CLAVE
                    [2] => NOMBRE
                    [3] => RFC
                    [4] => COMISION
                    [5] => IVA
                    [6] => SUBTOTAL
                    [7] => RETENCION
                    [8] => NETO
                    [9] => PRESTAMOS
                    [10] => NETO_A_RECIBIR
                )

        )
```

Comment: Have you checked value of `$highestColumn`?

Comment: On which position/line do you get the error? And shouldn't you put the contents of `$var` in  single quotes? I mean like `VALUES ('" . implode("','", $var) . "')";`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `implode` function needs a slight rework.

If you have `array('a','b','c')` and you want that to be a string **with quotes around each value**, you need to revise this line:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO bd_comisiones
  (registro,clave,nombre,rfc,comision,iva,subtotal,retencion,neto,prestamos,neto_a_recibir)
  VALUES ('" . implode(",", $var) . "')";
```

to be like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO bd_comisiones
  (registro,clave,nombre,rfc,comision,iva,subtotal,retencion,neto,prestamos,neto_a_recibir)
  VALUES ('" . implode('","', $var) . "')";
```

This will put `","` between each value, instead of just a comma.

If you're still troubleshooting it, try to `echo $sql;` to see the fully-formed SQL statement to make sure it looks okay.

Comment: awesome, but now there is no value on my bd

Answer (score 1):

Which line is your error occuring on?

And beyond that, your query will be incorrect:

```
$sql = "INSERT ... VALUES ('" . implode(",", $var) . "')";
                                        ^^^
```

This would produce

```
INSERT ... VALUES ('Registro,CLAV,...,NETO_A_RECIBIR')
```

which is a SINGLE string value. You want

```
$sql = "INSERT ... VALUES ('" . implode("','", $var) . "')";
                                         ^-^
```

isntead, so each individual component gets its own `'...'` quote set, producing

```
INSERT ... VALUES ('Registro','CLAV',...,'NETO_A_RECIBIR')
```

Comment: line 72, at query line by the way

Answer (score 0):

I've never used PHP Excel but I think that the problem is in your insert statement: when you implode your array there are only two quotes!

Simply change your line with this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO bd_comisiones (registro,clave,nombre,rfc,comision,iva,subtotal,retencion,neto,prestamos,neto_a_recibir) VALUES ('" . implode("','", $var) . "')";
```

Comment: yeah, totally works, but i don't have any values in my bd >.< just end the procces but do nothing

Comment: I can only suggest you to dump your variables (first of all check `$sql`and try to execute that code directly on your db).

Answer (score 0):

I thing you should put single quotes in the implode function like

```
VALUES ('" . implode("','", $var) . "')";
```

to get string like

```
VALUES ('A', 'B', 'C');
```

otherwise is just

```
VALUES ('A, B, C');
```